# Converting c# Rfc2898DeriveBytes encryption to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, rfc2898

Is there any functions in PHP that is equivalent to c# Rijndael AES encryption/decryption? I have include the c# code below. Please advise.

```
protected string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "test";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

Comment: AES encryption can be done with OpenSSL. https://secure.php.net/OpenSSL

Comment: I have a little lib to help with AES encryption and decryption, if you want I can post the github link as reference.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Is it similar with the sample function i posted?

Comment: I dont know C#, but the AES algorithm is everywhere the same.

Comment: So from looking at it I'd say it's about the same. It has IV, it has key,...

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Does it have salt too?

Comment: Salt...? You mean IV?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois oh ya, can you give me the github link so that i can refer it?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/CharlotteDunois/Encryption